# How reuse Angular modules in other projects

Tags: angular, module, code-reuse

I need to share a custom angular 2 module to other projects in my company.

For example:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BannerInlineComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class SpecialModule { }
```

Now, I want to use it in other projects using:

```
npm install my-special --save
```

And use:

```
import { SpecialModule } from 'my-special';
```

Comment: Did you find any solution??

Comment: @AdritaSharma, I found this explanation today. Could you check it please?
https://medium.com/@angularlicious/custom-angular-modules-a-guide-on-creating-publishing-and-using-angular-modules-75e26a04aa4b

Answer (score 0):

I found one option using Yoeman generator for angular library:

[generator-angular2-library](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library)

The generator creating a base of your module.

After this, I simulated the publication of my custom module in local NPM using:

[Sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia)

[Sinopia docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/keyvanfatehi/sinopia/)